# Trying to use a FORALL to insert data dynamically to a table specified to the procedure

Tags: oracle, associative-array, dynamic-sql, execute-immediate, forall

I have the need to dynamic know the name of the table that has the same data structure as many others and I can pass in a generic associative array that is of the same structure.  Here is the proc

```
PROCEDURE INSRT_INTER_TBL(P_TABLE_NAME IN VARCHAR2, P_DATA IN tt_type)

IS

BEGIN
    FORALL i IN P_DATA.FIRST .. P_DATA.LAST
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
          'INSERT INTO ' || P_TABLE_NAME ||
          ' VALUES  :1'
        USING P_DATA(i);
END INSRT_INTER_TBL;
```

I am getting the following error

ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist

What am I missing here?

So I had to specify all the columns necessary to insert to the table out in the insert statement like:

```
PROCEDURE INSRT_INTER_TBL(P_TABLE_NAME IN VARCHAR2, P_DATA IN inter_invc_ln_item_type)

IS

BEGIN
    FORALL i IN P_DATA.FIRST .. P_DATA.LAST
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
          'INSERT INTO ' || P_TABLE_NAME || ' (ITEM_PK, pk, units, amt) ' ||
          ' VALUES  (:P_INVC_LN_ITEM_PK, :PK, :UNITS, :AMT)'
        USING IN P_DATA(i).item_pk, P_DATA(i).pk, P_DATA(i).units, P_DATA(i).amt;
END INSRT_INTER_TBL;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TABLE` operator works better than a `FORALL` here.  It uses less code and probably skips some SQL-to-PL/SQL context switches.

```
--Simple record and table type.
create or replace type tt_rec is object
(
    a number,
    b number
);

create or replace type tt_type is table of tt_rec;

--Sample schema that will hold results.
create table test1(a number, b number);

--PL/SQL block that inserts TT_TYPE into a table.
declare
    p_table_name varchar2(100) := 'test1';
    p_data             tt_type := tt_type(tt_rec(1,1), tt_rec(2,2));
begin
    execute immediate
    '
        insert into '||p_table_name||'
        select * from table(:p_data)
    '
    using p_data;
    commit;
end;
/
```

You can run the above code in [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9870/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try `VALUES  (:1)`  i.e. have brackets around `:1`

Comment: tried that with no luck but that does bring up a good point.  This AA has 5ish columns in it, do I need to specify all of the columns in the values?  IE specify all column names and all values?   the table is unique among all associated tables except for 1 column and I got around that by creating a new type:that is generic for that one column which is a FK, pk value, so instead of like clm_pk, it is just pk in my record type

Comment: If you have more than just the column in the table, then, yes, it won't work unless you specified the columns you're inserting: `insert into table1 (col1) values (:1)` or what you did to have all columns